# real colorset in cpn tools and sml

Tags: sml, cpn-tools

I'm new in cpn tools and standard ml language. I want to define real colorset in cpn tools but it shows error:

```
real are not supported in cpn tools.
```

How can I do this without changing my IDE?
thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? In the meantime, [CPN-Tools Color sets](http://cpntools.org/2018/01/12/color-sets/) should explain some things.

Comment: when I define colset REAl=real; it shows this error(real are not supported in cpn tools.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real colorset is not supported in cpn tools  version3. If you want to declare real colorset you should use cpn tools version 4.